# How to efficiently create the same variables for each element of a list?

Tags: r, list

I am a long-time Stata user but am trying to familiarize myself with the syntax and logic of R. I am wondering if you could help me with writing more efficient codes as shown below (The "The Not-so-efficient Codes")

The goal is to (A) read several files (each of which represents the data of a year), (B) create the same variables for each file, and (C) combine the files into a single one for statistical analysis. I have finished revising "part A", but are struggling with the rest, particularly part B. Could you give me some ideas as to how to proceed, e.g. use `unlist` to unlist `data.l` first, or `lapply` to each element of `data.l`? I appreciate your comments-thanks.

### More Efficient Codes: Part A

```
# Creat an empty list
data.l = list() 

# Create a list of file names
fileList=list.files(path="C:/My Data, pattern=".dat")

# Read the ".dat" files into a single list
data.l = sapply(fileList, readLines)
```

### The Not-so-efficient Codes: Part A, B and C

```
setwd("C:/My Data")

# Part A: Read the data. Each "dat" file is text file and each line in the file has 300 characters.

dx2004 <- readLines("2004.INJVERBT.dat")
dx2005 <- readLines("2005.INJVERBT.dat")
dx2006 <- readLines("2006.INJVERBT.dat")


# Part B-1: Create variables for each year of data

dt2004 <-data.frame(hhx = substr(dx2004,7,12),fmx = substr(dx2004,13,14),
          ,iphow = substr(dx2004,19,318),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt2005 <-data.frame(hhx = substr(dx2005,7,12),fmx = substr(dx2005,13,14),
          ,iphow = substr(dx2005,19,318),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt2006 <-data.frame(hhx = substr(dx2006,7,12),fmx = substr(dx2006,13,14),
           iphow = substr(dx2006,19,318),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Part B-2: Create the "iid" variable for each year of data

dt2004$iid<-paste0("2004",dt2004$hhx, dt2004$fmx, dt2004$fpx,  dt2004$ipepno)
dt2005$iid<-paste0("2005",dt2005$hhx, dt2005$fmx, dt2005$fpx, dt2005$ipepno)
dt2006$iid<-paste0("2006",dt2006$hhx, dt2006$fmx, dt2006$fpx, dt2006$ipepno)

# Part C: Combine the three years of data into a single one

data = rbind(dt2004,dt2005, dt2006)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data from one of the input files, or some made up data? That way, we can test the code with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there. Its a combination of lapply and do.call/rbind to work with lapply's list output.

Consider this example:

```
test1 = "Thisistextinputnumber1"
test2 = "Thisistextinputnumber2"
test3 = "Thisistextinputnumber3"

data.l = list(test1, test2, test3)

makeDF <- function(inputText){
  DF <- data.frame(hhx = substr(inputText, 7, 12), fmx = substr(inputText, 13, 14), iphow = substr(inputText, 19, 318), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  DF <- within(DF, iid <- paste(hhx, fmx, iphow))

  return(DF)
}

do.call(rbind, (lapply(data.l, makeDF)))
```

Here `test1`, `test2`, `test3` represent your dx200X, and `data.l` should be the list format you get from the efficient version of Part A.

In `makeDF` you create your desired `data.frame`. The `do.call(rbind, )` is somewhat standard if you work with `lapply`-return values.

You also might want to consider checking out the `data.table`-package which features the function `rbindlist`, replacing any do.call-rbind construction (and is much faster), next to other great utility for large data sets.